# Calling a Fortran subroutine which uses module functions from R

Tags: r, fortran

I am trying to understand how to call Fortran from R. I'm ok with calling a code containing only a subroutine. However I would like to call a Fortran code that contains a module with functions used in a subroutine. Here is a simple example, that I compiled, but wasn't able to call from R using the command "dyn.load":

```
module forme
implicit none
public :: autoc

contains

function autoc(x,k) result(f_res)

 double precision, intent(in) :: x
 integer, intent(in)  :: k
 double precision :: f_res

 f_res=x+k

 return
 end function autoc

end module forme

subroutine invdeux(n,answer)
use forme
implicit none


integer, intent(in)::  n
double precision, intent(out)::  answer
double precision :: nreal 

nreal=n
answer=1/nreal
answer=autoc(answer,n)

end subroutine invdeux
```

Comment: How it wasn't able to load? Show us what you tried in R and show all your error messages.

Comment: Although not directly answering your question, I'll say that I've in general had a much better using `.C`/`.Call` and a C interoperable (`bind(c)`) wrapper subroutine than using `.Fortran` directly,

Comment: @francescalus. I've never had any trouble with using `.Fortran`. @HaMdi: show what you did exactly and show error messages.